# All items view does not show all the items in the list

Tags: designer-workflow, list-view, approval

My All Items view does not have any filters placed on it, yet some of the items are not showing up in the view. This occurs after an Approval workflow runs on the item and the items gets approved.

Any thoughts on what can be causing the problem?

Comment: Did you check item permission?

Comment: Are you applying the Break Inheritance?
If yes, Then need to check the permission of the current log-in user and move that particular user to the proper group where he/she can get the proper right or give the permissions to the current users group so that all the members from the current users group can get benefit for the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be item level permissions associated with the items that when it gets approved it will be only visible to some set of users of the one who created the item etc. Please check the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permissions on the items of the list. if All the permissions are requisite, try creating a new view with different name but same options to be shown. Sometimes view gets corrupt and messed up.